# How to assign public variable in angular 7 (always undefined)

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have following rest call for access data. The result is populate fine. But

```js
signin(signinData: signinData): any {
    const obj = { username: signinData.email, password: signinData.password };
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/fishproduct/login/", obj).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res["returnFlag"]);
        this.status = res["returnFlag"];
        console.log(this.status);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

    return this.status;
  }
```

and I have a public variable called 
**public status: any**

but when  i return the value of status it always undefined.

Comment: You need to understand that your operation is async - meaning that you have no guarantee that `this.status` will be assigned before you return it from the function. My suggestion is to return the whole observable and use the data in your component.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that